# If the limit of a function when x goes to infinity is infinity, does that mean the integral from 1 to infinity is also infinity?

Tags: calculus

If the limit of a function when x goes to infinity is infinity, does that mean the integral from 1 to infinity is also infinity?

Can we use the above to show that an unsolvable integral is infinity?

**edit:** Can we also say that if the limit of a function when x goes to infinity is a number then the integral is not infinity?

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $f$ is a "reasonable" function on $[1,\infty)$ then indeed $\int_1^\infty f(x) dx$ makes sense and is $\infty$. I'm not sure what your second question means; perhaps you want to prove that $\int_1^\infty e^{x^2} dx = \infty$ (or something like that) without an antiderivative?

Comment: @Ian: Can we use the above to show that the integral logx^logx with the above theory is inf?

Comment: @Ian: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Yes to the first, yes to the second, no to the third (if the function has a horizontal hasymptote different from the x axis then the integral will diverge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral

$$\int_{1}^\infty f(x)dx$$

is **defined** as

$$\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_1^b f(x)dx$$

so it should be simple for you to show that if there exist $x_0\geq 1$ and $M>0$ such that $f(x)>M$ for all $x>x_0$ (this is of course true of $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$), then $$\int_{1}^\infty f(x)dx = \infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your edit question "Can we also say that if the limit of a function when x goes to infinity is a number then the integral is not infinity?" is No.
As an example, take the constant function $f(x)=1$. The its limit when x goes to infinity is 1, but its integral from 1 to infinity is infinity.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, then we have that $f(x)\ge M$ for some $M>0$ when $x>x_0$. Hence, we have that
$$
\int_1^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx
=\int_1^{x_0}f(x)\mathrm dx+\int_{x_0}^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx
\ge\int_1^{x_0}f(x)\mathrm dx+M\int_{x_0}^\infty \mathrm dx=\infty.
$$

Comment: Heh wow, we even used the same variable names ($f, M, x_0$)

Comment: @5xum Nice!${}{}$